# using windows .bat file to commit and push on git

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have the following code in a .bat file to backup a memory stick and then push the backup to git, the first part of the backup works but it wont push to bitbucket?

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set datestamp=%dt:~0,8%
set timestamp=%dt:~8,6%
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set Min=%dt:~10,2%
set Sec=%dt:~12,2%

set stamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%-%Min%
mkdir "C:\Users\Jonny\Desktop\backup\%stamp%"
xcopy "D:\*.*" "C:\Users\Jonny\Desktop\backup\%stamp%" /e /s /d

start "" "C:\Users\Jonny\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\git-bash.exe" --login
cd C:/Users/Jonny/Desktop/backup
git add .
git commit -am "made changes"
git push
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Can you share it?

Comment: Not getting an error the folder is created in Windows as expected but not pushed to bit bucket

Answer (score 0):

Check

- what a git log/git status give you in "C:\Users\Jonny\Desktop\backup
- if there is any gitignore rule which might explain why the new folder is not added/committed/pushed

That is:

```
cd C:\Users\Jonny\Desktop\backup
git check-ignore -v -- %stamp%\afile
```

(replace `%stamp%` by an actual created time-stamped folder)

Comment: so how to put few conditions here. like, let's say your push fails. and you want to give a try again.

Comment: @SagarNayak It would be best to ask a separate question with more details